# Is the Nokia BH-214 bluetooth headset compatible with Android?

Tags: bluetooth-audio, headset

I have a Nexus S with Android 4.1.2.

I purchased a Nokia BH-214 headset. The audio output works. The buttons work. But for some reason, the headset's microphone seems to be ignored by the phone. When I make a call, it uses the phone's microphone instead of the one in the headset. Is this some compatibility problem or I am doing something the wrong way?

Comment: Have you tried re-pairing it again? The phone might have missed the `headset` profile and only used the `media` profile particularly when used first time.

Comment: Is the device compatible with Android smartphones having bluetooth version 4.0?